# Why tchdb file size keep going bigger after tchdbout some items?

Tags: tokyo-cabinet

I use tchdb in a server to store some data. And use another program to clean some old and useless data. But after executing this `cleaner` the file size didn't change and keep going bigger while the server still running. Did I do things wrong? Should I do something else in the server after executing the cleaner?

Open mode for tchdbopen is `HDBOREADER | HDBOWRITER | HDBOCREAT | HDBONOLCK`.